# Rubik's cube with simulated annealing

Tags: c++, performance

I wanted to write a c++ program to solve a 3x3 rubik's cube using algorithm named simulated annealing, but failed at it. This idea appeared when I watched this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyyVbuLZav8

So I find some information about that, and i found this text(All other articles depends on this):

[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322222373_Solving_the_Rubik's_Cube_using_Simulated_Annealing_and_Genetic_Algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322222373_Solving_the_Rubik%27s_Cube_using_Simulated_Annealing_and_Genetic_Algorithm)

But when I tried to write something similar, happened that the best solution is only 33 good squares.

Can anyone help me? This is the program I wrote(All void functions is just rotation of cube, i think there are no problems, because I mix cube with this, and anyway it could find solution):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int a[3][18], a1[3][18];


void xclockwiserotate1() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][3] = b[0][6]; a[0][4] = b[0][7]; a[0][5]= b[0][8];
    a[0][6] = b[0][9]; a[0][7] = b[0][10]; a[0][8] = b[2][11];
    a[0][9] = b[0][12]; a[0][10] = b[0][13]; a[0][11] = b[0][14];
    a[0][12] = b[0][3]; a[0][13] = b[0][4]; a[0][14] = b[0][5];

    a[0][0] = b[2][0]; a[0][1] = b[1][0]; a[0][2] = b[0][0]; // |
    a[1][0] = b[2][1];                      a[1][2] = b[0][1]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][0] = b[2][2]; a[2][1] = b[1][2]; a[2][2] = b[0][2]; // |
}


void xcounterclockwiserotate1() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }


    a[0][9] = b[0][6]; a[0][10] = b[0][7]; a[2][11]= b[0][8];
    a[0][6] = b[0][3]; a[0][7] = b[0][4]; a[0][8] = b[0][5];
    a[0][3] = b[0][12]; a[0][4] = b[0][13]; a[0][5] = b[0][14];
    a[0][12] = b[0][9]; a[0][13] = b[0][10]; a[0][14] = b[0][11];

    a[0][0] = b[0][2]; a[0][1] = b[1][2]; a[0][2] = b[2][2]; // |
    a[1][0] = b[0][1];                    a[1][2] = b[2][1]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][0] = b[0][0]; a[2][1] = b[1][0]; a[2][2] = b[2][0]; // ||
}


void xclockwiserotate2() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][0] = b[2][14]; a[1][0] = b[1][14]; a[2][0]= b[0][14];
    a[2][14] = b[0][15]; a[1][14] = b[1][15]; a[0][14] = b[2][15];
    a[0][15] = b[0][6]; a[1][15] = b[1][6]; a[2][15] = b[2][6];
    a[0][6] = b[0][0]; a[1][6] = b[1][0]; a[2][6] = b[2][0];

    a[0][3] = b[2][3]; a[0][4] = b[1][3]; a[0][5] = b[0][3]; // |
    a[1][3] = b[2][4];                      a[1][5] = b[0][4]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][3] = b[2][5]; a[2][4] = b[1][5]; a[2][5] = b[0][5]; // |
}


void xcounterclockwiserotate2() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][15] = b[2][14]; a[1][15] = b[1][14]; a[2][15]= b[0][14];
    a[2][14] = b[0][0]; a[1][14] = b[1][0]; a[0][14] = b[2][0];
    a[0][0] = b[0][6]; a[1][0] = b[1][6]; a[2][0] = b[2][6];
    a[0][6] = b[0][15]; a[1][6] = b[1][15]; a[2][6] = b[2][15];

    a[0][3] = b[0][5]; a[0][4] = b[1][5]; a[0][5] = b[2][5]; // |
    a[1][3] = b[0][4];                    a[1][5] = b[2][4]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][3] = b[0][3]; a[2][4] = b[1][3]; a[2][5] = b[2][3]; // |
}


void xclockwiserotate3() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[2][0] = b[2][5]; a[2][1] = b[1][5]; a[2][2]= b[0][5];
    a[2][5] = b[0][17]; a[1][5] = b[0][16]; a[0][5] = b[0][15];
    a[0][17] = b[0][9]; a[0][16] = b[1][9]; a[0][15] = b[2][9];
    a[0][9] = b[2][0]; a[1][9] = b[2][1]; a[2][9] = b[2][2];

    a[0][6] = b[2][6]; a[0][7] = b[1][6]; a[0][8] = b[0][6]; // |
    a[1][6] = b[2][7];                      a[1][8] = b[0][7]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][6] = b[2][8]; a[2][7] = b[1][8]; a[2][8] = b[0][8]; // |
}


void xcounterclockwiserotate3() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][17] = b[2][5]; a[0][16] = b[1][5]; a[0][15]= b[0][5];
    a[2][5] = b[2][0]; a[1][5] = b[2][1]; a[0][5] = b[2][2];
    a[2][0] = b[0][9]; a[2][1] = b[1][9]; a[2][2] = b[2][9];
    a[0][9] = b[0][17]; a[1][9] = b[0][16]; a[2][9] = b[0][15];

    a[0][6] = b[0][8]; a[0][7] = b[1][8]; a[0][8] = b[2][8]; // |
    a[1][6] = b[0][7];                    a[1][8] = b[2][7]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][6] = b[0][6]; a[2][7] = b[1][6]; a[2][8] = b[2][6]; // |
}


void xclockwiserotate4() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][2] = b[0][8]; a[1][2] = b[1][8]; a[2][2]= b[2][8];
    a[0][8] = b[0][17]; a[1][8] = b[1][17]; a[2][8] = b[2][17];
    a[0][17] = b[2][12]; a[1][17] = b[1][12]; a[2][17] = b[0][12];
    a[2][12] = b[0][2]; a[1][12] = b[1][2]; a[0][12] = b[2][2];

    a[0][9] = b[2][9]; a[0][10] = b[1][9]; a[0][11] = b[0][9]; // |
    a[1][9] = b[2][10];                      a[1][11] = b[0][10]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][9] = b[2][1]; a[2][10] = b[1][11]; a[2][11] = b[0][11]; // |
}


void xcounterclockwiserotate4() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][17] = b[0][8]; a[1][17] = b[1][8]; a[2][17]= b[2][8];
    a[0][8] = b[0][2]; a[1][8] = b[1][2]; a[2][8] = b[2][2];
    a[0][2] = b[2][12]; a[1][2] = b[1][12]; a[2][2] = b[0][12];
    a[2][12] = b[0][17]; a[1][12] = b[1][17]; a[0][12] = b[2][17];

    a[0][9] = b[2][9]; a[0][10] = b[1][9]; a[0][11] = b[0][9]; // |
    a[1][9] = b[2][10];                      a[1][11] = b[0][10]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][9] = b[2][1]; a[2][10] = b[1][11]; a[2][11] = b[0][11]; // |
}


void xclockwiserotate5() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[0][0] = b[2][3]; a[0][1] = b[1][3]; a[0][2]= b[0][3];
    a[2][3] = b[2][15]; a[1][3] = b[2][16]; a[0][3] = b[2][17];
    a[2][15] = b[2][11]; a[2][16] = b[1][11]; a[2][17] = b[0][11];
    a[2][11] = b[0][2]; a[1][11] = b[0][1]; a[0][11] = b[0][0];

    a[0][12] = b[2][12]; a[0][13] = b[1][12]; a[0][14] = b[0][12]; // |
    a[1][12] = b[2][13];                      a[1][14] = b[0][13]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][12] = b[2][14]; a[2][13] = b[1][14]; a[2][14] = b[0][14]; // |
}


void xcounterclockwiserotate5() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[2][15] = b[2][3]; a[2][16] = b[1][3]; a[2][17]= b[0][3];
    a[2][3] = b[0][0]; a[1][3] = b[0][1]; a[0][3] = b[0][2];
    a[0][2] = b[2][11]; a[0][1] = b[1][11]; a[0][0] = b[0][11];
    a[2][11] = b[2][15]; a[1][11] = b[2][16]; a[0][11] = b[2][17];

    a[0][12] = b[0][14]; a[0][13] = b[1][14]; a[0][14] = b[2][14]; // |
    a[1][12] = b[0][13];                      a[1][14] = b[2][13]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][12] = b[0][12]; a[2][13] = b[1][12]; a[2][14] = b[2][12]; // |
}


void xclockwiserotate6() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[2][3] = b[2][12]; a[2][4] = b[2][13]; a[2][5]= b[2][14];
    a[2][12] = b[2][9]; a[2][13] = b[2][10]; a[2][14] = b[2][11];
    a[2][9] = b[2][6]; a[2][10] = b[2][7]; a[2][11] = b[2][8];
    a[2][6] = b[2][3]; a[2][7] = b[2][4]; a[2][8] = b[2][5];

    a[0][15] = b[2][15]; a[0][16] = b[1][15]; a[0][17] = b[0][15]; // |
    a[1][15] = b[2][16];                      a[1][17] = b[0][16]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][15] = b[2][17]; a[2][16] = b[1][17]; a[2][17] = b[0][17]; // |
}


void xcounterclockwiserotate6() {
    int b[3][18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    a[2][9] = b[2][12]; a[2][10] = b[2][13]; a[2][11]= b[2][14];
    a[2][12] = b[2][3]; a[2][13] = b[2][4]; a[2][14] = b[2][5];
    a[2][3] = b[2][6]; a[2][4] = b[2][7]; a[2][5] = b[2][8];
    a[2][6] = b[2][9]; a[2][7] = b[2][10]; a[2][8] = b[2][11];

    a[0][15] = b[0][17]; a[0][16] = b[1][17]; a[0][17] = b[2][17]; // |
    a[1][15] = b[0][16];                      a[1][17] = b[2][16]; // |->  rotation of one side
    a[2][15] = b[0][15]; a[2][16] = b[1][15]; a[2][17] = b[2][15]; // |
}


void top_bottom_counterclockwise() {
    xcounterclockwiserotate1();
    xcounterclockwiserotate6();
}

void top_bottom_clockwise() {
    xclockwiserotate1();
    xclockwiserotate6();
}

void left_right_clockwise() {
    xcounterclockwiserotate2();
    xcounterclockwiserotate4();
}

void left_right_counterclockwise() {
    xcounterclockwiserotate2();
    xcounterclockwiserotate4();
}

void front_back_clockwise() {
    xclockwiserotate3();
    xclockwiserotate5();
}

void front_back_counterclockwise() {
    xcounterclockwiserotate3();
    xcounterclockwiserotate5();
}

int main() {
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    double T = 5000, probability;
    int f = 0, f1 = 0, ma = 0;
    srand(time(0));


    vector<void(*)()> v;
    v.push_back(xclockwiserotate1); v.push_back(xcounterclockwiserotate1);
    v.push_back(xclockwiserotate2); v.push_back(xcounterclockwiserotate2);
    v.push_back(xclockwiserotate3); v.push_back(xcounterclockwiserotate3);
    v.push_back(xclockwiserotate4); v.push_back(xcounterclockwiserotate4);
    v.push_back(xclockwiserotate5); v.push_back(xcounterclockwiserotate5);
    v.push_back(xclockwiserotate6); v.push_back(xcounterclockwiserotate6);
    v.push_back(top_bottom_counterclockwise); v.push_back(top_bottom_clockwise);
    v.push_back(left_right_counterclockwise); v.push_back(left_right_clockwise);
    v.push_back(front_back_counterclockwise); v.push_back(front_back_clockwise);


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
            fin >> a1[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 100000; k++) {
        f = 0; f1 = 0;
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
                if (a1[i][j] == ceil((double(j + 1)) / 3.0)) {
                    f += 1;
                }
                a[i][j] = a1[i][j];
            }
        }
        void (*call)() = v[rand() % 18];
        call();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] == ceil((double(j + 1)) / 3.0)) {
                    f1 += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        probability = exp(double(double(f1 - f)) / T);
        T = T * 0.95;
        if ((f - f1 <= 0) || ((double)(rand()) / RAND_MAX < probability)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
                    a1[i][j] = a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        if (f1 >= 54) {
            cout << "Solution Found";
            break;
        }
        ma = max(ma, f);
    }
    cout << ma;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the code doesn't do what you need it to do, it's not ready for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast It could be there is no flaw, the simulated annealing algorithm is non-deterministic so there is always a chance it doesn't find the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>`

You might have learned this from some coding site or course, however `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard C++ header. There is no guarantee it exists or what its contents are, so please [do not use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Instead, `#include` the [standard library headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) that are needed for your program. In this case those are:

- `<vector>` for `std::vector`
- `<fstream>` for file I/O
- `<cstdlib>` for the C random number functions
- `<cmath>` for the math functions
- `<algorithm>` for `std::max`

## Avoid `using namespace std`

This saves a bit of typing perhaps, but
by `using namespace std` you are pulling everything from `std` into the global namespace, including things you did not know about. It is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), and instead you should avoid using it. More appropriate would be to only include the things you need, for example you could write:

```
using std::vector;
```

So you can write `vector<…>` without needing the `std::`.

## Use C++'s random number generators

Instead of using `srand()` and `rand()`, prefer using [C++'s random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), which have a much higher quality and avoid many of the issues with C's random number facilities. See the below code for how to use it in your program.

Note that you call `srand(time(0))` every iteration of the outer `for`-loop. Since `time(0)` returns the time in seconds as an integer, that means that if many annealing steps are done in one second, they would all use the same choice for the "random" move, which is not what you want.

## Avoid global variables

The arrays `a` and `a1` are global variables. In a larger program, global variables can become problematic: they make the code less flexible, and there is a potential for conflicts in the global namespace. There are various ways around it. In this case I recommend:

## Create a `class RubiksCube`

You can organize your code better by creating a `class` that represents the state of a Rubik's cube, and has member functions to modify and query that state. You can make it so your code in `main()` looks like:

```
int main() {
    // Initialize the cube
    RubiksCube cube("input.txt");
    int fitness = cube.fitness();
    int max_fitness = fitness;

    // Initialize the random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0.0, 1.0);

    // Perform the annealing
    double T = 5000;

    for (int k = 0; k < 10000000; k++) {
        // Do a move on a copy of the cube and calculate the new fitness
        RubiksCube new_cube = cube;
        new_cube.random_move();
        int new_fitness = new_cube.fitness();

        // Check if we want to keep the new cube
        double probability = std::exp((new_fitness - old_fitness) / T);
        T *= 0.95;

        if (new_fitness >= fitness || dist(gen) < probability)  {
            cube = new_cube;
            fitness = new_fitness;
            max_fitness = std::max(max_fitness, fitness);
        }

        // Exit if we found the solution
        if (fitness == 54) {
            std::cout << "Solution Found";
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << max_fitness;
}
```

Note how this now looks much simpler; only one `for`-loop is left. Creating `class RubiksCube` is left as an excercise for the reader, but it's not much more than moving your existing functions into that class as member variables, and adding a constructor that reads from a given file and a copy constructor that copies the state.

## You are dropping the temperature too quickly

I was a bit curious about the factor 0.95 being applied to `T` at every step. This would *very rapidly* decrease `T`: after 1000 steps, `T` would be \$5000 \cdot 0.95^{1000} \approx 2.6 \cdot 10^{-19}\$. Checking the paper, it mentions that there are *two* loops: one that "repeats until frozen", the other "do N times". `T` is not modified in the inner loop. You should do the same, otherwise the system freezes too quickly and will never be able to escape a local maximum found in the first few hundred steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But anyway with two loops it works better, but still bad. Is it possible to solve it like this?

Comment: I don't know. The paper is a bit vague about the exact number of steps they do in the inner loop and how long everything takes. You could try reproducing their graphs and see if they match.